# How to load each cookie file in a folder with pickle or something?

Tags: python, python-os

In my cookies folder, there are many files cookies1.txt, cookies2.txt, ... and below is my script, I tried to use it to login to facebook with cookies, with each cookie file it will load and execute an action then finish and perform the next load file. It works well when I just put a cookie file in a folder but when I put two or more in a folder, it shows an error.

```
import os
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
files = os.listdir("cookies")
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
for f in files:
    cookies = pickle.load(open(f, "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tuong cat/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/new.py", line 10, in <module>
    cookies = pickle.load(open(f, "rb"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cookies2.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to provide to open() is the full path to your cookies file.

Otherwise you are just checking in the current work directory which obviously doesn't have this file in it since it is inside the cookies folder.

I think the following code snippet should help clarify things:

```
full_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "cookies", f)
cookies = pickle.load(open(full_path , "rb"))
```